# ReactDom not rendering React Elements to DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am attempting to build a React app with a Django backend. However React is not rendering any elements to the html page. For some reason my index.js file is not connecting with my index.html file and grabbing the root div element by id. I created my react app with npx-create-react-app. The elements were rendering in the beginning, however I am incorporating google maps API into my project and after I did that React stopped rendering elements to the DOM. I have been stuck on these for about 2 days and I am at a lost. I have read through similar stack overflow questions and haven't been able to find an answer, Help is greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

Index.js:

'''

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App/App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import CHICHEN_ITZA from './Monuments/Chichen_Itza/Chichen_Itza'

// window.RenderCall=function(id){
//   ReactDOM.render(
//     <React.StrictMode>
  
//       <App />
//       <h1>This is in Index.js</h1>
//       <CHICHEN_ITZA/>
  
//     </React.StrictMode>,
//     document.getElementById(id)
//   );
  
// };

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>

    <App />
    <h1>This is in Index.js</h1>
    <CHICHEN_ITZA/>

  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

as you can see from commented out code I attemtpted to call the ReactDom render method from a script tag as a function from my html.index and that failed. Here is my html.index:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />

    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- <script src="../src/index.js"></script> -->
    
    <div id="root"></div>

    <H1>THIS IS ON THE INDEX.HTML</H1>
    <!-- <script src="index.js">
      RenderCall('root_id');
    </script> -->
  </body>
</html>
```

The H1 element, in the body of the html renders, but nothing from my index.js renders onto the html div. I tried changing the id of 'root' too and that didn't work. I imagine it has something to do with bundle or babel.

I also attempted to include my index.js as a script on my index.html page but that didn't work. I have the google api in a .env file in the directory containing my react project. The api key is accessed by a class component within the src directory. I don't know if that is relevant but I thought I would include it just in case.

here are the errors I am getting in the console when I open up the developer console:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
MapContainer.js:29 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'MAPS_API_KEY')
    at Module../src/MapContainer/MapContainer.js (MapContainer.js:29:1)
    at Module.options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:61:1)
    at Module../src/App/App.js (bundle.js:18:84)
    at Module.options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:61:1)
    at Module../src/index.js (Chichen_Itza.js:21:1)
    at Module.options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
```

Here is my MapContainer.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { Map, GoogleApiWrapper } from 'google-maps-react';

const mapStyles ={
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%'
  };
  
  export class MapContainer extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <Map
          google = {this.props.google}
          zoom = {14}
          style = {mapStyles}
          initialCenter={
            {
            lat: -1.2884,
            lng: 36.8233
            }
          }
        />
      );
    }
  }

  export default GoogleApiWrapper({
      apiKey: ProcessingInstruction.env.MAPS_API_KEY
  })(MapContainer)
```

Comment: Blank screens in React are generally associated with errors, because React refuses to run if your code has an error. Open the browser console (`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`J`) and paste your error in your question.

Comment: In your HTML you're not importing any JavaScript; what do you expect to happen?

Comment: I thought react bundles the javascript in automatically. @code, what call should I make so that the jsx runs through the bundle.

Comment: @code Updated the question with the error from my console.

Comment: Hmm.. do you write a file called `MapContainer.js`? If so can you post that as well?

Comment: @code, just updated with the MapContainer.js file

Comment: `ProcessingInstruction.env`?? Is this some auto-correct mistake? Normally it's `process.env`

Comment: As Phil printed out, `ProcessingInstruction.env` doesn't look quite right to me. Did you mean process? This could likely be the problem as your error says that the API key is undefined.

Comment: @Phill, Changed ProcessingInstruction.env to process.env and the DOM rendered. Thats an autocrorect mistake for the record books!!! 2.5 days! Thanks Guys, Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

`Unchecked runtime.lastError...` This error message is telling you React is not rendering because you have a runtime error in `MapContainer.js` line 29:
That is `apiKey: ProcessingInstruction.env.MAPS_API_KEY`.
Did you mean `proccess.env.MAPS_API_KEY`?